# Accessing types in another project from a DLL (C#)

Tags: c#

I'm looking to load a DLL into another project (Assembly.Load*() etc, at runtime). It would be much simpler for me if there were a way to include the types (i.e. classes) from the main assembly, into the DLL, so I can pass them (well, objects) in method calls.

In C++ I could just include the declarations, but (so far as I know) there's no way to do that in C#. I may end up having to just 'reference' the whole main program into the DLL's, but it seems like there's gotta be a better way.

(Basically the DLL's are runtime modules, which need info from the main program to do processing on. However the main assembly also needs access to quite a bit of the stuff the modules need access to.)

Comment: Could you provide the code please for more understanding?

Comment: In a case like this, it seems like you are looking to make another project that houses all your classes that will be shared.  Then you can reference the dll in your main project and any others that might need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an application design problem, resulting in circular references - your dlls need classes from application and applicaiton needs classes from dll.

You should try refactoring your project to avoid this situation. Specifically, code in your DLLs should not directly access the main app.

You can define an interface in a shared DLL

```
interface IFoo{
   int GetBar();
}
```

Then use it in your Dll's code as a parameter

```
void DoSomeStuff(IFoo foo);
```

And create an actual implementation in your application:

```
class Foo:IFoo{...}
```

That way you can do something in main app from the  DLL without referencing the app from the DLL.

Comment: "Specifically, code in your DLLs should not directly access the main app."

Right. I'm not trying to access the main app, per se, but need to be able to pass data from the main app into functions in the DLL. The interface idea is great though - thank you!