# Access type from outside of a DLL

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, types

So I'm making a C# library library which is supposed to convert an object into a string and do stuff with it. Problem is, I cannot access the type of that object. The type is defined in the project in which the DLL will eventually be used, but I don't know how to access it.

I've only found [Accessing types in another project from a DLL (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019995/accessing-types-in-another-project-from-a-dll-c).

Is there any other way besides letting the user handle the string convertion himself and just use a delegate like:

public void DoStuff(Object obj, Func convertToString) { string s = convertToString(Obj) }

I don't really want the user to do it on his down.

Comment: This is a bit unclear, If you add the dll as a reference you your project, add a using clause for your namespace and try to create the type, what happens?

Comment: I want to use the type inside the dll.

Comment: Aye, the procedure above is how you do that ... if its not working or what you want to do you need to add more details.

Comment: I was looking for a way to protive the convertToString function inside the dll. I as a human know what type obj will have, but in the code I don't.